# python with MySQLdb user input date

Tags: python, mysql-python

I keep being returned blank data from the datatbase when using:

```
id = str(raw_input("Enter Date to run such as YYYY-MM-DD:  "))
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM appointment a where a.AptDateTime Like %s limit 0,100",id)
```

I think that an extra backtick is being sent with the query, but not sure-

Brad

Comment: Shouldn't it be `appointment as a`?

Comment: No. That's for column alias.

Comment: Try trimming your input. If that doesn't work please post your input and one of your records that should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming in this answer that `AptDateTime` is a [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) column.

Don't query with `LIKE`:

```
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * FROM apt WHERE aptdatetime LIKE %s', '2013-12-22')
0L
```

Use the [`DATE()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to extract the date and query with `=`:

```
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * FROM apt WHERE DATE(aptdatetime) = %s', '2013-12-22')
1L
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth!, I was able to get the correct records returned using your suggestions.